# how to calculate width for custom scrollbar according to the div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I hav a div container and i am making a custom scrollbar for it. The problem now i am facing is how to calculate the width of the scollbar and set it.

Since the width of my div changes dynamically, the scrollbar width also should change according to the div. I am unable to calculate the width for scrollbar.

This is my code.

```css
#track{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container{
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position:absolute;
}
#top{
    width:10px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
#bottom{
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="track">
    <div id="container">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </div>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

For now, the width is assigned statically. I want to calculate the width of scrollbar according to the width of the div `container` dynamically and set to it.

For example, go to this link `jsfiddle.net/d7pqbkrx/`. Change the width of the container, the scrollbar width will automatically gets changed according to the `container` width. So, like that, i want to change my scrollbar width dynamically.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: use jscrollpane : http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: @Viktor Maksimov Actually i should not use any plugins. I have some limitation in it. For me everything is working except this width. Can you help with that?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the width of the scrollbar is it the hickness or the position?

Comment: @Antonio Smoljan I changed the question. Please see that and help me :)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something with Jquery:

```
$('#container').width();
```

Will return the width of your div#container. You can write a function and run this every time you update the content of your div:

```
function checkContainerWidth(){
    var width = $('#container').width();
    console.log(width);
    return width;
};
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
function setScrollbarWidth(){
    var width = checkContainerWidth();
    $('#scrollbar').css("width", width);
};
```

Comment: Actually i want to set width for scrollbar and by getting the width of the container, how can i set the width for the scrollbar ?

Comment: I changed the question. Please see that and i want to get like that

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you just need to put your scrollbars inside the container since it already has a position property other than `static` the top and bottom scrollbars can be positioned to the edges

[example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/mepzxr?editors=110)

Changint the container's width moves the scrollbars.

Code:

```
#container{
  padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    position:absolute;
}
#top{
    width:10px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
#bottom{
    width:100px;
    height:10px;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute; 
}
```